# How can I request the first 100 titles in NewsAPI instead of first one?

Tags: python, newsapi

Here, the code returns the first article's title according to the search information

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?qInTitle=bangladesh&from=2023-07-17&to=2023-08-16&sortBy=popularity&language=en&apiKey=45c28deca60947fd9ec4d8db2b2c4a81")
content = r.json()

print(content['articles'][0]['title'])
```

How can I make it so that it returns the first 100 or something similar?

I've tried to remove the `[0]` and putting `[0:100]` instead  but it didn't work; I am new to coding I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?qInTitle=bangladesh&from=2023-07-17&to=2023-08-16&sortBy=popularity&language=en&apiKey=45c28deca60947fd9ec4d8db2b2c4a81")
content = r.json()

for row in content['articles'][:100]:
  print(row['title'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `for` loop to iterate the first 100 elements (or rather "news"):

```py
import requests

r = requests.get("https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?qInTitle=bangladesh&from=2023-07-17&to=2023-08-16&sortBy=popularity&language=en&apiKey=45c28deca60947fd9ec4d8db2b2c4a81")
content = r.json()

articles = content['articles']

for index in range(0, 99):
    print(articles[index]['title'])
```

I've put 99 because the array indexes is starting from 0 but not 1 and 100 - 1 is 99.

For each iteration, the `print` function will output the title of article with the `index`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to acquire (up to) 100 titles then:

```
import requests

URL = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything'
PARAMS = {
    'qInTitle': 'bangladesh',
    'from': '2023-07-17',
    'to': '2023-08-16',
    'sortBy': 'popularity',
    'language': 'en',
    'apiKey': '45c28deca60947fd9ec4d8db2b2c4a81'
}
MAX = 100

with requests.get(URL, params=PARAMS) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    if (content := response.json()).get('status') == 'ok':
        for article in content.get('articles', [])[:MAX]:
            print(article.get('title'))
```

**Output (partial):**

```
Bangladesh grapples with record deadly outbreak of dengue fever - Reuters
Political party supporters, police clash in Bangladesh - Reuters
Bangladesh to tone down law critics accuse of crushing dissent - Reuters
Injured Tamim steps down as Bangladesh ODI captain, to miss Asia Cup - Reuters
...
Bangladesh dealing with worst dengue fever outbreak on record - Yahoo Canada Sports
WHO urges swift action as dengue cases surge in Bangladesh - Al Jazeera English
Boat carrying dozens sinks in Bangladesh capital Dhaka
UNICEF appeals for funding as record 300,000 children enrolled in Bangladesh Rohingya camps
```